# Yii2 : I Can't type anything if select2 in modal

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, jquery-select2

I'm using Kartik Select2 Widget ...  but the problem is I can't type anything in the search.

I used this code:

```
`<?= Html::button('حجز موعد ', ['value'=>URL::to('index?r=event/create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-block btn-flat','id'=>'creates']) ?>
<?php 
    Modal::begin([
        'options' => [
        'id' => 'kartik-modal',
        'tabindex' => false
        ],
        ]);
    modal::end();
?>`
```

JS Code:

```
`$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#creates',function(){
    var date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
    $.get('?r=event/create',{'date':date},function(data){
    $('#modal').modal('show')
    .find('#kartik-modal')
    .html(data);
    });  
   });
  });`
```

my problem is : the text disabled

[image: pic]

If not in modal it works fine !

[image: pic]

Comment: [Refer this issue.](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2/issues/159)

Comment: @Insane I did as they said ..the ID=  kartik-modal'  and         'tabindex' => false . But it doesn't  work

Comment: Add `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;` in JS.

Comment: that's true ...  I didn't notice that .. thank you

Comment: that's weird .. it works for just  one time after that it doesn't work.

Comment: Where you added above JS line? Update question with JS.

Comment: it works now with this code : `$(function(){
$(document).on('click','#creates',function(){
 var date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
 $.get('?r=event/create',{'date':date},function(data){
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
 $('#modal').modal('show')
 .find('#modalContent')
 .html(data);
 }); 
});
});` thank you